# Adding separator between arrow icon and text in select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a select menu and I am using Bootstrap 4. I replaced background to replace arrow icon in select element, but now I need to add border left to that image, I am not finding anyway.

For reference, I am attaching Image of what's required
[image]

and this is what I have achieved so far

[image]

and code I did till now
HTML

```
<select class="custom-select">
  <option disabled>Choose 1</option>
  <option>another</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

And this is my CSS

```
.custom-select {
  background: #fff url("/assets/images/down-arrow.png") no-repeat right 0.75rem center;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
}
```

Comment: Post the HTML too please.

Comment: Can't you add the html and css from the select? It's easier to test

Comment: .custom-select {
                background: #fff url("/assets/rogers/images/down-arrow.png") no-repeat right 0.75rem center;
                background-size: 12px 12px;
                direction: rtl;
            } @Usman Tahir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the select in another DIV (eg. `custom-select-wrapper`) and use a CSS psuedo element for the border...

https://www.codeply.com/go/edxDmWNLx6

```
<div class="custom-select-wrapper">
  <select classs="custom-select">
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
    <option>opt3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-select-wrapper {
 position: relative
}
.custom-select-wrapper:after {
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  content:"\00a0";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 46px;
  z-index: 2;
  display:block;
  height: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use another image for the `line` in the background as well or make a combined image of `arrow` and `line`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.custom-select {
  background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/118/118738.png") no-repeat right 0.75rem center, url("http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/brackets/presentation_form_for_vertical_low_line_uFE33_icon_128x128.png") no-repeat right 2rem center;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @UsmanTahir I have just used the dummy image...you can use your own image from the design..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you wrap the select in a div and add an after to it

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select class="custom-select"></select>
</div>
```

Than, in CSS you add the arrow with an after

```
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.select-wrapper select {
  background: transparent;
}

.select-wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 12px;
  background: #fff url("/assets/rogers/images/down-arrow.png") no-repeat right 0.75rem center;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

I couldn't test the code, because you didn't share your HTML, so I just gave you an example.

Or than you can add the line to the arrow image